# Factoring $4x^{4} - x^{2}$ into $4x^{2}(x-1/2)(x+1/2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

So i was trying to make an integral but i'm stuck with the easiest part.

> How do you get this?
> $$4x^{4} - x^{2} = 4x^{2}(x-1/2)(x+1/2)$$

I know how to take the roots $x = 0$, $x = \pm 1/2$,
but when putting it all together I get
$$x(x−1/2)(x+1/2)$$ and I can't remember how to do it correctly.

Comment: Welcome to the MSE community! Do you mean $4x^{4} - x^{2}$?

Comment: My bad, i meant 4x^4 - x^2

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant $4x^{4} - x^{2}$. In such case, you can factor $x^{2}$ out and apply the following identity:

\begin{align*}
a^{2} - b^{2} = (a+b)(a-b)
\end{align*}

At your case, you have $4x^{4} - x^{2} = x^{2}(4x^{2} - 1)$, where $a = 2x$ and $b = 1$. Consequently, we get that
\begin{align*}
4x^{4} - x^{2} = x^{2}(2x-1)(2x+1) = 4x^{2}(x-1/2)(x+1/2)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand where the 4 comes from, I'm sure it's easy and i'm making it difficult, but I don't get it.

Comment: There's no problem at asking. Notice that $2x - 1 = 2(x - 1/2)$ and $2x + 1 = 2(x + 1/2)$.

Comment: Thank you! I get it this way, the problem is that I don't understand how to get there instead of factoring it, finding its roots (x = 0 and x = ±1/2) and once you've got them, factor it.

Comment: In general, given a polynomial of degree two $p(x) = ax^{2} + bx + c$, we can factor it as follows

$$p(x) = a(x-r_{1})(x-r_{2})$$

where $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ are its roots. At your case, $p(x) = 4x^{2} - 1$, where $a = 4$, $r_{1} = 1/2$ and $r_{2} = - 1/2$.